# Will the IRS penalize me if I mail my tax forms before the deadline but it arrives after it?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040

I just filled out my federal taxes, 1040 and 1040-V. Deadline is July 15th.

I've tried filing online but I can't seem to find any websites that just have the 1040 to fill out and submit. It always asks me several questions that I don't know to and asks me to fill out other forms instead of 1040 and 1040-V. Several of them which I don't know the information for. I have no w-2 income

---

Therefore I am considering to mail my paper tax forms in with my check. Since the due date is July the 15th, it's likely my mail won't get there by then. Would I be facing penalties?

Or if anyone knows how to fill out the 1040 and 1040-V and submit online that'd be good too. I just can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You have no W2 income - okay, but where do you have income from then?

Comment: The 1040 form is just a summary.  What other forms you need to fill out depends on what income, deductions, and credits you have.  The 1040-V will spit out if you have not had enough withheld so you are due a refund. If you don't have the information, just file the automatic extension.  That gets you until October 15 to gather it, but you need to estimate your taxes now and make sure you have paid at least enough.  Otherwise there will be a penalty due, but if you file the extension it is not so bad.  The due dates are satisfied by postmark, not receipt at the IRS.

Comment: If you have Internet access, for detailed, step-by-step instructions that cover _most_ people see [publication 17](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-17). Some relatively rare items and provisions are excluded from pub17 but it explicitly refers you to the other pubs or forms/instructions needed.

Comment: Wait, is post so bad in the USA that you can’t get a letter delivered inside five days? I am in the UK and can post something to the other side of Europe and be fairly confident of it arriving by tomorrow, or the day after at the latest.

Comment: @Darren Depends if you're sending it by ground or air mail; base post is the former and you appear to be underestimating how large the US is.  It's about 40-50 hours (lowest in the south, highest in the north) of driving time from one side of the US to the other (for comparison, London to Moscow is only 32h according to Google maps, London to Warsaw is half that).  Chunked into daily drive segments with un/reloading from one truck to the next (ie not loaded into a truck going non-stop to the other coast just needing driver swaps) and about a week is normal.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I’m not underestimating. The size of the continental states is comparable to Europe, hence my example. What’s different is that we put a letter in the post and it just goes via the most efficient method. There is no choice between air and ground mail, letters to Europe will be sent via air by default.

Comment: @Darren  A much larger fraction of US mail goes coast to coast than makes equivalently long trips in Europe; sending that much via airmail would significantly increase our base postal rates for the 99% of the time where it doesn't matter in order to send a lot more via more expensive and polluting air freight; instead it's sold as a premium service where if you absolutely need next day service it's available as a premium service.

Comment: @Darren The USPS will generally deliver mail in the continental US (i.e. not including Alaska and Hawaii) in three to four days. They absolutely won't guarantee it though (unless you pay extra).

Comment: Selecting ground vs air mail hasn't been a thing in the U.S. for domestic mail since 1977.  Lots of long distance first class mail goes by air.  As @Darren says for europe, the post office chooses the most efficient method for the distance.

Comment: @user4556274 they don't explicitly call it ground vs air anymore; but if you want the next day delivery quality of service guarantee that comes from flying an item to the closest airport, instead of normal first class/priority mail (same 3 day or less nominal target, just more detailed tracking/etc for the latter) you upgrade all the way to the top of the line Priority Mail Express product.

Comment: @Darren https://www.stamps.com/usps/usps-delivery-times/ 1-3 days for letters or large envelopes, delivered for around a dollar or less.  https://www.royalmail.com/sending/international/country-guides/germany shows more like $2 in 3-5 days just London to Frankfurt (under 500 miles, a little over *half* the distance from Chicago to New York).

Comment: And - just to be clear, the real concern on the matter of taxes isn't postal delivery (1-3 days, most likely, even if postmarked wasn't the standard), it's the *opening* time - that will take much longer.

Comment: @Joe W-2 is not the only possible source of income.  The many 1099 forms come to mind very quickly.

Comment: @AleksG Certainly, but the idea is for OP to mention what those are as it could impact the answer (given OP is asking about forms).

Comment: @Joe Not that I want to drag this out any more but I know from experience a first class letter posted today in the UK will be anywhere in the EU by the next day. The German or other countries’ postal services may vary.

Comment: The relevant IRS website: https://www.irs.gov/filing/individuals/when-to-file

Comment: @Darren Please, fly to boston and drive to LA. It’d be the equivalent of you driving to Tehran.

Comment: @Darren: As long as none of the postal workers of the various countries are out on strike, anyway.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just mail your taxes in, you're fine as long as you are *postmarked* by July 15.  IRS won't actually *open* it for days, or even weeks, likely, but you'll be in the clear.

The most "generic" version is [Free File Fillable Forms](https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/before-starting-free-file-fillable-forms), which is basically "fill your 1040 out online and then send in the result".

As to whether you need to fill out other forms or not, will depend on your income (and deduction) streams.  If you have nothing but normal plain old wage income, then you just need the 1040 and W-2s and a few other trivial things (like the "Yes, I promise I had health insurance" and such); the Free File Fillable Forms will take care of you there.  But if you had capital gains, if you sold stocks, if you withdrew from your IRA, if you had employment-related deductions - then you might need some other things.  Free File Fillable Forms can cover most of that.

Comment: I hope you meant 'withdrew' from _401(k)_ or _IRA_ or maybe _529_, but not _1040_. And TCJA'17 eliminated the PPACA 'responsibility payment' (aka tax) as of 2019, so 2019 form 1040 no longer has the 'health coverage' checkbox, and form 8965 for exemptions no longer exists. TCJA also 'suspended' the former 2%-floor deductions, including unreimbursed employee expenses. (_Self-employed_ still can deduct valid business expenses on C or C-EZ.)

Comment: Yes, meant IRA, thanks for noticing!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I think I got an ulcer from that comment, is it really that complicated to file taxes in usa?! you dropped 10 - 15 weird names of forms and differen things :O Where I'm at I get it pre-filled online and just tick a box "it looks alright" and send it off.

Comment: @DakkVader It's not much more complicated than that for most people in the US, either. For example, "529" is a reference to a type of education savings account. Contributions are not (with a handful of state-level exceptions) deductible, but withdrawals (including post-contribution growth) is not taxed as long as the money is used for a qualifying education expense. It's certainly more complicated than it needs to be, but it's also easy to make it sound even worse.

Comment: I think they'll actually _open_ it.  Checks you send get processed rather fast.

Comment: Further to @davidbak's comment I mailed the payments for my returns and estimated taxes over the July 4th weekend, effectively on July 6. The federal payments cleared on July 9th.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - gosh it just occurred to me - maybe they have machines that detect, through the envelopes, the MICR ink on the checks and then only immediately open the ones containing payments?  The rest just get stuck in huge bags for later?

Comment: @davidbak Much simpler I'm sure - they open them, split them into "returns" and "checks" and "other stuff", and then cash the checks.  I'm not sure if they attempt to scan in the returns (in which case perhaps those get handled quickly also now, for the most part) entirely by machine, or if human intervention is needed, in which case that part probably takes longer.  But I also think they must've sped up some - much of the reason for delaying tax due date was to spread the returns out more to give them more time to process.

Comment: @DakkVader taxes can be a complete pain in the ass here. I spent a couple hours doing mine and apparently still got them wrong because they sent me a check for overpaying. And I don't own a business or anything like that which would make them overly complicated. Run-of-the-mill life events can cause them to be a pain, and most people will pay for software or a professional to do them.

Comment: I vouch for the Free File Fillable Forms. I've been living abroad and sending my tax returns by post for many years.  On a couple of occasions they've been lost in the post and I had to send in a "replacement".  I would then have to attach the original proof of posting to justify the delay.  This year I used the Free File Fillable Forms - and it does the job very well.  It easily handled the 1116 and 2555 forms, too.  And, best of all, it on the fly checks for the obvious mistakes (like missed fields, etc.) and warns you.

Comment: @Joe: IIRC from the days when I actually mailed in paper forms with checks, it's even simpler than that.  Returns with checks enclosed go to a different post office box.  The on-line Free Fillable Forms work quite well, in my experience.  The only real problem is that decoding their error messages is anything but obvious.  I usually have to use Google to find out what they really mean.

Comment: @jamesqf Ah - yes, you're right, I'd forgotten that.

Comment: Another +1 for Free File Fillable Forms. I've been using it for years. The only year I've ever had any issue filing my tax return was the year I wasn't able to use that and had to send a paper copy instead (because a required form from a special program that year had no online-filing option.) Your returns also generally get processed much faster if you file online than if you send a paper copy. I usually have my refund in my bank account within 1-2 weeks after filing online. The year I had to file on paper, they claimed I didn't sign it and it took them _3 months_ to process it.

Answer (score 9):

No problem.

The IRS scans your envelope when they scan your documents.  In any subsequent review or audit, they **can, will and do** look at the postmark when deciding things.  And the postmark is what matters.

US post offices used to be open til midnight on April 15, *for that exact purpose*.  Postal workers would literally stand at streetside and take tax forms from people driving up!  However e-"file" did away with that.

Comment: I used to enjoy doing that - and there were others too apparently as there was typically a long line of cars at 11:30PM at the main transfer post offices near San Francisco Airport also SeaTac airport.  (With post office workers there to handle the crowd.) But now, yes, TurboTax and e-filing work for me, and I seek entertainment elsewhere.

Comment: I've heard stories about tax documents and checks being sent from Post Offices in remote Alaska so that it was still postmarked by 4/15 (normal year), but had a significant time in transit for the money to earn interest before it was needed when the check cleared.

Comment: The Boston Fort Point Postal Annex keeps normal hours till midnight.  Does get lively on those filing nights.

Comment: I also dropped my taxes off with minutes to spare, in Richmond, VA over 20 years ago.  It sounds like every large town had at least one Post Office that stayed open until midnight.

Answer (score 6):

The IRS considers the postmark date to be the date of filing, so it's perfectly fine so long as your envelope makes it to your post office by the close of business on the due date.  This is true for the return itself and any payments made by check.

If you're particularly concerned about having proof of timely filing, consider using [Certified Mail](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/What-is-Certified-Mail).  The post office postmarks the envelope in front of you and also hands you a postmarked receipt as proof of mailing.  This also gives you a tracking number that allows you to verify delivery.

---

The legal authority for the timely filing rule is codified under [26 C.F.R. § 301.7502-1](https://casetext.com/regulation/code-of-federal-regulations/title-26-internal-revenue/chapter-i-internal-revenue-service-department-of-the-treasury-continued/subchapter-f-procedure-and-administration/part-301-procedure-and-administration/judicial-proceedings/civil-actions-by-the-united-states/3017502-1-timely-mailing-of-documents-and-payments-treated-as-timely-filing-and-paying), *Timely mailing of documents and payments treated as timely filing and paying*.

> A document or payment is deemed to be filed or paid on the date of the postmark stamped on the envelope or other appropriate wrapper (envelope) in which the document or payment was mailed. Thus, if the envelope that contains the document or payment has a timely postmark, the document or payment is considered timely filed or paid even if it is received after the last date, or the last day of the period, prescribed for filing the document or making the payment.

For international filers, also relevant is [Revenue Ruling 2002-23, 2002-18 IRB 811](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-irbs/irb02-18.pdf) which holds that official postmarks from foreign postal services are also valid for the purposes of determining timely filing.

In addition to the USPS and foreign postal services, the IRS maintains a [list of designated private delivery services](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm139798498231088) which qualify to meet the timely filing rule.  As of 2020, that list is certain services from DHL, UPS, and FedEx.

---

Finally, there are a number of 100% free e-filing options available if you meet the [qualifications](https://www.irs.gov/filing/free-file-do-your-federal-taxes-for-free), but they are hard to find thanks to dark patterns employed by the tax prep industry.

[This list](https://www.turbotaxsucksass.com/) allows you to cut though to the actually free programs.  (There's also [Credit Karma Tax](https://www.creditkarma.com/tax), which is free and available to everyone.)

Online programs generally ask you a series of basic questions to determine what kind of income you had, taxes you've already paid, and credits and deductions you're eligible for.  **If you don't know the answers to those questions, it's likely that you aren't able to fill out the 1040 *correctly* yourself.**

You should learn the answers to those questions before you file to ensure that your return is accurate.  You may be missing out on money due to you otherwise.

Also note that generally, once you complete online tax programs, they will allow you to download the completed 1040 (and other forms) as a PDF before you file.  You could do this to compare with the version you've already completed, and then e-file if it looks good.  (And really, you should download and save this PDF for your records anyway.)

If you need more time to understand the questions or seek advice, the IRS will grant an automatic 6-month extension to the return due date so long as you file [Form 4868](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f4868.pdf) before the due date.

Comment: +1 for the part in bold, especially. I hope OP pays attention to that. (The rest of the answer is good, too.)

Answer (score -2):

not if you ensure that the post office puts the actual date on the envelope to prove when it was mailed.  I would mail certified to ensure you have a copy proving it.

One USPO tried to not postmark my return and they were caught putting a later postmark on all mail intentionally to make their stats look better.

So watch them put the date on and do not let them put tomorrows date or anything else other than the correct date.  And check your receipts before you leave.